# Expanding partition for more

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, swap

I formatted the unallocated space to fat32 (don't know if that was right). Now I want to extend my dev/sda5 for more memory as I'm currently getting warnings about my low memory space. Above My /dev/sda5 is New Partition #1 with 19.53 gigs and below it is the linux-swap. I can take memory from the linux swap as well as I have quite a bit of RAM.

I read that I'm meant to boot off USB and run GParted, unswap the linux-swap and then delete it. Unmount the sda5 and after that, resize the /dev/sda5 to take up some of that hard drive space and then turn on swap afterwards. Is this right? Double checking because I already messed it up once.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUADP.png]

Thank so much! Reading from here: http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Comment: Please stop reading from there and start reading from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the mount point to "/"

then in terminal:

```
sudo update_grub
```

The swap of 4 GB is more than enough if you have RAM >= 8 GB .

Comment: I'm assuming you set the mount point of the unallocated space but how do you set the mount point?

Comment: in the photo you provided, the mount point "/" is at your ext4 drive, after expanding it, make sure you keep the mount point "/" at ext4 drive.